# SDL2 desired multiple key sticky controls, difficulty preventing early key up misinterpretation as new command

Tags: c++, sdl, keyboard-events, sdl-2

In short, I am having trouble implementing *non-buggy* directional keyboard controls (up, down, left, right, and two-key combinations of those keys) so pressing one of the combinations (or single keys) has a sticky key effect. That is, up + left should result in the game object staying in the up + left position.

Unfortunately, that is not what is happening.
If I tap one of the two-key combinations, more often than not the program will mis-interpret the small delay between letting go one of the two keys as a key press. So down + right might be interpreted as (down+right, *nevermind* right).

I have encountered the same problem in, for example, Processing, and it makes sense to some degree that it happens. If you treat the arrow keys as a virtual d-pad, how would one tell the difference between up + right and up + right but switching to up immediately? The required logic is not exactly clear.

I have looked on stackoverflow and the official SDL forums for solutions, but nothing seems to help me with this particular case. This was the closest question I could find: [A way to make keyboard event queue both responsive and not take whole CPU power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845491/a-way-to-make-keyboard-event-queue-both-responsive-and-not-take-whole-cpu-power)

Some "solutions" I have tried include: checking whether the same keys are held on the next iteration (in other words, wasting a frame... this almost worked but not always, and it seemed to be a hacky way to go) or only checking for keyboard input every 4 iterations. Neither of these yield a very good result.

Note that in my program, up/down, left/right, up+left/down+right, and up+right/down_left are considered the same commands, so there are four options.

The main loop omitting rendering logic:

```
while (is_running)
{
    const Uint8 up = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_UP];
    const Uint8 down = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN];
    const Uint8 left = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT];
    const Uint8 right = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT];

    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                is_running = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    if ((up || down) && (!left && !right))
    {
        if (prev != 0) // to avoid printing the same position repeatedly
        {
            puts("UP/DOWN");
            prev = 0;
        }   
    }
    else if ((left || right) && (!up && !down))
    {
        if (prev != 1)
        {
            puts("LEFT/RIGHT");
            prev = 1;
        }
    }
    else if ((up && left) || (down && right))
    {
        if (prev != 2)
        {
            puts("UP-LEFT/DOWN-RIGHT");
            prev = 2;
        }
    }
    else if ((up && right) || (down && left))
    {
        if (prev != 3)
        {
            puts("UP-RIGHT/DOWN-LEFT");
            prev = 3;
        }
    }
}
```

(Another Note: I intend to use bitmasking rather than the many boolean checks seen above, but this does not relate to the problem.)

I set the program to output the direction to the console.

```
Output:

UP/DOWN
LEFT/RIGHT
UP/DOWN
UP-RIGHT/DOWN-LEFT // worked here
UP-LEFT/DOWN-RIGHT // worked here
UP-RIGHT/DOWN-LEFT // did not work here, reverted to LEFT/RIGHT
LEFT/RIGHT // unexpected
UP-LEFT/DOWN-RIGHT // also did not work here, reverted to LEFT/RIGHT
LEFT/RIGHT // unexpected
```

The results are seemingly random, and strangely, it's even worse if I separate the cases into up, down, left, right, up+right, down+right, down+left, up+left.

My best guess? I need some sort of timing mechanism and/or a solution that uses the event system.

I think that I've hit a bit of a dead end. May I please have help resolving the issue? It's the main problem that prevents me from completing my game demo.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: I figure that the greatest challenge is differentiating between switching from a diagonal to vertical or horizontal *without letting go of all the keys* and the natural slight delay between letting go of one key and the other when simply tapping a key combination.

EDIT 2: This *mostly* (some exceptions) works, except I cannot transition from diagonal to orthogonal without releasing all keys. It might be impossible to get a completely smooth version without having all the keys be released first without changing the orientation. Still, I would think that this would be possible with a game controller...it's definitely done in practice. Why not with a keyboard?

```
while (is_running)
{       
    /*
    const Uint8 up = (key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_UP] == 0) ? 0 : UP;
    const Uint8 down = (key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN] == 0) ? 0 : DOWN;
    const Uint8 left = (key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT] == 0) ? 0 : LEFT;
    const Uint8 right = (key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] == 0) ? 0 : RIGHT;
    */



    bool _u = false;
    bool _d = false;
    bool _l = false;
    bool _r = false;

    Uint8 key_down = 0;
    bool single_key_down = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                is_running = false;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    switch (event.key.keysym.scancode)
                    {
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_UP:
                            _u = true;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN:
                            _d = true;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT:
                            _l = true;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT:
                            _r = true;
                            break;
                    }
        }
    }

    const Uint8 up = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_UP];
    const Uint8 down = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN];
    const Uint8 left = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT];
    const Uint8 right = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT];

    if ((_u && _l) || (_d && _r) 
        || (up && left) || (down && right))
    {
        if (prev != 2)
        {
            puts("UP-LEFT/DOWN-RIGHT");
            prev = 2;

        }
        which_index = 2;

    }
    else if ((_u && _r) || (_d && _l) 
             || (up && right) || (down && left))
    {
        if (prev != 3)
        {
            puts("UP-RIGHT/DOWN-LEFT");
            prev = 3;
        }
        which_index = 3;
    }
    else if (_u || _d)
    {
        puts("UP/DOWN");
        which_index = 0;
    }
    else if (_r || _l)
    {
        puts("LEFT/RIGHT");
        which_index = 1;
    }
}
```

EDIT 3:

Less of a seamless rotation (no hold-like-a-d-pad-ness), but less strain on fingers since you can just tap. This seems to have no flaws:

```
while (is_running)
{       
    /*
    const Uint8 up = (key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_UP] == 0) ? 0 : UP;
    const Uint8 down = (key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN] == 0) ? 0 : DOWN;
    const Uint8 left = (key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT] == 0) ? 0 : LEFT;
    const Uint8 right = (key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] == 0) ? 0 : RIGHT;
    */



    bool _u = false;
    bool _d = false;
    bool _l = false;
    bool _r = false;

    Uint8 key_down = 0;
    bool single_key_down = true;
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                is_running = false;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                    switch (event.key.keysym.scancode)
                    {
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_UP:
                            _u = true;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN:
                            _d = true;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT:
                            _l = true;
                            break;
                        case SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT:
                            _r = true;
                            break;
                    }
        }
    }

    const Uint8 up    = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_UP];
    const Uint8 down  = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN];
    const Uint8 left  = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT];
    const Uint8 right = key_states[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT];
    bool none_held = false;
    if (up || down || left || right)
    {
        keys_reset = true;
    }
    else
    {
        none_held = true;
    }

    if (!none_held && keys_reset)
    {
        if ((_u && _l) || (_d && _r) 
            || (up && left) || (down && right))
        {
            if (prev != 2)
            {
                puts("UP-LEFT/DOWN-RIGHT");
                prev = 2;
            }
            which_index = 2;
            keys_reset = false;
        }
        else if ((_u && _r) || (_d && _l) 
                 || (up && right) || (down && left))
        {
            if (prev != 3)
            {
                puts("UP-RIGHT/DOWN-LEFT");
                prev = 3;
            }
            which_index = 3;
            keys_reset = false;
        }
        else if (keys_reset)
        { 
            if (_u || _d)
            {
                if (prev != 0)
                {
                    puts("UP/DOWN");
                    prev = 0;
                }
                which_index = 0;
                keys_reset = false;
            }
            else if (_r || _l)
            {
                if (prev != 1)
                {
                    puts("LEFT/RIGHT");
                    prev = 1;
                }
                which_index = 1;
                keys_reset = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll never get two keys to release at the same time; there will always be some delay that leaves a gap for your main polling loop to run before the second key release is processed.

You'll have to adapt your logic to handle this.  Possibly don't allow switching from a multiple key combination (UP-RIGHT) to a single one (UP) without releasing all keys.  Or get rid of the multikey combinations altogether and use another single key (Home, Page Up, etc).

You also need to consider what happens if the user has 3 or 4 keys pressed, either being held or momentarily during a transition.

Comment: Thanks, but I sort of figured that might be part of the problem. Please take a look at an edit to my main post to see what I figured so far. Basically you can't transition to a single key from a combination. Only a single tap will work. The problem is that I liked the idea of supporting taps as well as d-pad  style. I'd think that I'd have to handle similar logic with a gamepad for input, in which case there must be a way to support taps as well as holding multiple at once.  The game is fast-paced. Anyway, I'm having trouble with the coding logic. How would the "no switching" version look?

Comment: More specifically, if there is no solution that allows for holding as well as tapping, how would I check that all keys are released?

Comment: @synchronizer All keys are released when no keys are pressed.  D-pads are simple things, and can be designed in a way so that diagonals can be held with one finger and released pretty cleanly.  Their output is typically 4, 5, 8, or 9 bits.  A keyboard can be quite complicated, with its own programmable microcontroller (key delay, repeat rates, lights).  Holding a diagonal generally requires using two fingers on the keys, resulting in longer gaps between the two key releases.  Maybe add something so that if a direction is held less than 1/4 second it reverts to the previous direction?

Comment: I see, so if I were to program d-pad support I would probably have to note that the controls are a little different (possibly better). For now what I did is shown in my third edit above. It's not perfect (still a little twitchy when not letting go of all keys), but now I can reliably tap and get the correct result. I can try the timing suggestion you just made. As for the d-pad version of the controls, I will probably get to it later, but from your description it sounds much easier to diferentiate between diagonals on, for example, a playstation controller than on a keyboard.